# Tabulating data using Core Data - How to filter effectively?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I'm building an app for reporting sales figures. The Core Data structure is as follows

```
Product <---->> SaleAggregate
Customer <---->> SaleAggregate
```

SaleAggregate is the total sales per Product, per Customer for a certain month. This entity has a 'Month', 'Year' and 'Amount' property.

I'm trying to display this in a tabular format as follows (a separate table for each Customer)

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Product | 01/2011 | 02/2011 | 03/2011 | 04/2011 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Gizmo   |      40 |     120 |      83 |      48 |
| Widget  |      92 |      38 |      37 |      36 |
| Thingy  |      12 |      84 |      29 |      40 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Each customer can have sales logged for any number of products, and I need to retrieve all of those sales, somehow group them by the product and then display each SaleAggregate 'Amount' with the corresponding month/year.

I can easily retrieve all SaleAggregates for a Customer with an NSPredicate, and all unique Products sold to a customer with an NSPredicate and `@distinctUnionOfObjects`, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

The table is implemented with a UICollectionView, but I'm not quite sure what the logic should be to put the right value in the right cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Is it just a case of retrieving every SaleAggregate in one query and then filtering the array with an NSPredicate for the correct month/year for each cell that I want to display? I'm thinking there has to be a smarter way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand this right, an example of SalesAggregate object having amount , say 40 is the amount of one particular product bought by one particular customer in a particular month?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Using predicates and filtering you could get the following for a particular customer?

```
ProductArray:
SalesAggreateDateArray:
```

---

```
if section ==0 
      row==0 --> "Product"
      rest of the rows --> [ProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
else if row ==0
      sections --> [SalesAggregateDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
else
       each cell --> [SalesAggregateAmountObjects filter with 
                                 date= date at row 0, indexPath.section and 
                                 product = product at section 0, indexPath.row]
```